# Monitoring all traffic through a router/network?

Tags: networking, monitoring

I and my colleagues are doing a project where we have to analyze traffic of a group of volunteers. Where they will connect to the network using WIFI/Ethernet. ALL their traffic especially searches made on google and other search engines are to be logged. The volunteers are free to use any device, hence the solution needs to be platform independent for the clients and traffic needs to be logged to a system running linux (probably ubuntu). A solution without a lot of packet analysis will be appreciated as this would be time consuming.

The network and router is our own and any solutions including using the router is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: What suggestions/options has your own research provided?

Comment: Wireshark has come up a lot. But its a little too low level for our purpose, but any methods to circumvent this will be most welcome. Using a some kind of DNS service like OpenDNS is another option but all the logs are kept on their server which we do not personally prefer. A way to use/make our own DNS would be nice (If its actually (practically) possible).

Comment: Does your router not log all this traffic if you turn logging on (if not, search if any do)?

Comment: You must use _Content Sniffer_ .

Comment: @DaveRook Unfortunately no. I have heard of dd-wrt firmware for routers but ours is not compatible with it.

Comment: @SuB Could you elaborate ? All I could find was that it is to find MIME type.

Comment: I think you need application layer date not whole packet data. So you need a program which reassemble packets and give you application layer data, e.g. a HTML page of visited web site. Xplico is one of these programs.

Comment: @SuB Xplico seems to be what I need and from the screenshots and reviews looks promising. I will try and post the results soon.